# How can I run a node.js server

Tags: node.js, server

I'm new to node and have many things unclear.

Like, for php, I just need a index.php file on server's root dir and it can work by itself.

However, for a node.js file, we need to "node" command it in terminal right?

So what if we close that terminal? How can I keep it running to accept my requests?

Comment: You may need more help than can be provided here. You start by comparing index.php with the process running the node server. It is going to be hard to help you.

Comment: I learnt node with the tutplus tutorial in one week, you can also use it step by step http://code.tutsplus.com/series/nodejs-step-by-step--net-20500

Comment: I have experience of developing php. It's natural for me to compare these two. So could you give me some advice about where to start?

Comment: *"However, for a node.js file, we need to "node" command it in terminal right?"* well, with php you have to tell apache (or whatever webserver you are using) to pass .php files through the php interpreter. It's just that most installations perform that step for you. With node, node is itself a webserver. You don't setup a node interpreter, instead you simply route requests to the node webserver (which will be running on a port of it's own.) You can (and should) have the node webserver start at server boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in saying that the 'node' command will start a node process with whatever script you supply to it.

As far as keeping it running, there are several ways to do it.  There are plenty of CLI libraries that will help you.  For example, this one is called [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever)

If you are using linux, you can simply run the node process as a background task:

```
node server.js &
```

Comment: Another popular option is PM2. And when running `node` directly your app will just go offline if it crashes for some reason. Forever, PM2 and other tools will restart it automatically and keep logs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To run node without terminal, you might want to check out one of these modules depending on your platform:

[node-mac](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-mac)

[node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows)

[node-linux](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-linux)